# calculator convert string to integer code in mips assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

Im having trouble completing and understanding this mips code

About a calculator program that can calculate integer addition / subtraction written using the MIPS assembler. 
 The input is given to the array of Formula char (base address $ s0) in the form of a formula. 
 The null character (\ 0, ASCII code 0) is placed at the end.  The calculation result is given to the register $ s1 and the overflow is ignored. 
 For example, if the input is Formula = “100 + 20 + 3”, $ s1 = 123, and if Formula = “− 100 + 20-3”, $ s1 = −83 is output. 
 The '+' and-in the program are the characters + 'and-, in ASCII respectively, and the ASCII characters are 0..9 are  48 (10), 49 (10) and 57 (10).

im having hard times to debug this.

```
.text
.globl main

        main: 
        la $s0,word ##copy base address of array to t1
       add $s1, $zero, $zero 
        add $s2, $zero, $zero
        Addi $s3,$zero,1
        Addi $t1, $zero,'+'
        Addi $t2,$zero,'-'
        addi $t3,$zero,10

        Loop: lb $t0,0($s0)
        Addiu $s0,$s0,1 
        Beq $t0,$t1,Plus
        Beq $t0,$t2,Minus
        Beq $t0,$zero,Cal
        Addi $t0,$t0,-48 
        Mul $s2, $s2, $t3
        Add $s2,$s2,$t0
        J Loop

        End:



       li $v0,1
        move $a0,$s1
        syscall
        li $v0, 10
       syscall

          Plus: addi $s4, $zero, 1
          j Cal 
          Minus: addi $s4, $zero, 0
          Cal: beq $s3,$zero,Subn
          Addn: 

          add $s1,$s1,$s2

          beq $s4,1,Join //im not sure here

          Subn: sub $s1,$s1,$s2
          Join : add $s2,$zero,$zero
          Beq $t0,$zero,End
           Add $s3,$s4,$zero
           J Loop


       Exit:
       li $v0, 10
       syscall

      .data
       word: .asciiz "-100+20+3"
        result: .asciiz "$s1->"
        prompt: .asciiz "$s0->"
```

However when debugging this code produce -77, but the correct result is -83

However when debugging this code not work, is there wrong part??

Comment: Can the assembly code call standard C functions, is that allowed? Then why not simply call `strtol` or `atoi`? Or maybe use `scanf` to read the integer values as integers?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no :( im struggling.. as im not quite understand the role of $s4, $s3 register here :(